# Why is my little program crashing just after I run it

Tags: c++, debugging, crash

I'd like to know and understand why does my little console program crash after I run it, right in the beginning, even though it compiled successfully.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> valueWithUnit;

    {
        std::string unit = '\0';
        std::string convertNumb = '\0';
        for (double forVal; std::cin >> forVal; ) {
            std::cin >> unit;

            if (unit != "cm" || unit != "m" || unit != "in" || unit != "ft") {
                std::cout << "The unit you entered is not supported by this program.";
                std::cout << " Try again with \"cm\", \"m\", \"in\", \"ft\"\n";
            }
            else {
                convertNumb = forVal;
                valueWithUnit.push_back(convertNumb + unit);

                if (valueWithUnit[valueWithUnit.size() - 1] == "100cm") {
                    std::cout << "That's also 1 meter.\n";
                }
                else if (valueWithUnit[valueWithUnit.size() - 1] == "2.54cm") {
                    std::cout << "That's also 1 inch.\n";
                }
                else if (valueWithUnit[valueWithUnit.size() - 1] == "1in") {
                    std::cout << "That's also 2.54 centimeters.\n";
                }
                else if (valueWithUnit[valueWithUnit.size() - 1] == "1ft") {
                    std::cout << "That's also 12 inches.\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (std::string i : valueWithUnit) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

When I debug it it tells me this:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00191644 in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
>   If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Seems like the problem has to do with my vector but I still don't get it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it let you input the length and unit?  Did you step through the code and see on what line the exception happens?

Comment: If you input an invalid unit the program will exhibit UB. The vector will be empty, and will be accessed just afterward with the array subscript operator `[]`. Is that what's happening?

Comment: Nope, it crashes right after I run it. Couldn't find on what line the exception happens either.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (unit != "cm" || unit != "m" || unit != "in" || unit != "ft") {
```

If this `if` expression evaluates to true, note that the execution path will **not** insert a new value into the `valueWithUnit` vector. Then...

```
if (valueWithUnit[valueWithUnit.size() - 1] == "100cm") {
```

... and if this is the initial, very first iteration of the loop, the `valueWithUnit` vector will still be empty, because the previous `if` statement skipped insertion of a value into the `valueWithUnit` vector.

So, valueWithUnit.size() will return zero here. You can figure out the rest of this bug all by yourself.

Comment: I corrected the code. It should have been like it is now on the question, all those else ifs should have been inside of the else that is enabled if the unit checking is evaluated to false.
Still has the error though, so the question persists.

Comment: You're also using `||` when you should be using `&&`. Did you not step through the program with a debugger?

Comment: I'm usually still confused with && and || but I always realize that after I try to use my programs ahah. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing strings with an integral constant 0 which is causing your program to crash when you declare `unit` and `convertNumb`.

That's because the integral value 0 (namely `'\0'`) is treated as a nullpointer value  when it's passed to the `string` constructor that expects a `char const*` argument (any integral constant 0 can be used as a nullpointer value).

Change `std::string unit = '\0';` to `std::string unit;`. And the same for `convertNumb`.

That will define it as empty string. You don't have to worry about the null terminator when using strings in c++.

Comment: Well, I learned on the internet somewhere that '\0' was a good initialization method but seems like it wasn't. It actually worked @puqeko , I also thought it would be strange for the crash to happen just because I initialized to NULL but seems like it really was it.
Thanks ;) Gotta do some research on initialization again, ahah.

PS: Can't upvote you because of low reputation :c

Comment: @puqeko: My mistake - I misread it as `"\0"` (which is valid), rather than `'\0'`, which is not (because it's actually just `0`, i.e. a NULL pointer). You're absolutely right! (The best code would still be a simple `std::string unit;`).

Comment: @b1GZZ: It's a good initialisation method for C-strings (i.e. pointers-to-`char`), but you're not using C-strings.

Comment: On a side note: `string` is a class, not a type like `char`. That's why it behaves differently.